# Android get context from non Activity Class

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-context

I m creating an open source library for android in this library I should call a method on application start. After this method call I need to get context. Is there a way to get current context or activity from a static class without pass Context parameter to method. Is android send an intent when an activity start.

Comment: Why don't you want to pass the `Context` as parameter of the method ? It's the best way to do it.

Comment: Becuse I m creating a third party library and I dont want to developers need to call a method inside every activities onCreate methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass an Instance of `Context` via Constructor

```
class YourClass {
    private Context context;

    public YourClass(Context context) {
        this.context=context;
    }    
}
```

Comment: This is solution but I need to call this constructor only one time. After then when the activity change the context parameter should change without calling a method. Is it possible via broadcast receiver or something else.

Comment: What about If you have a base activity class and that should be extended by your users ?

Comment: I asked it to my investor few days ago to this idea but he says we need to minimalize the effort for developers to implement our library. He does not like this idea because there are a lot of library types like sherlock activity or List Activity etc. Is android supports multiple inheritence ?as I know it is impossible. I thing i need to create Multiple base activities for each type of activity. This might be best solutoin if there is no way to get context without calling a method.